# C#: Counting number of elements between nodes in LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list

I want to calculate the total number of nodes between a start node and and end node in a **System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList**, similar to the STL algorithm **std::count** in C++ (except that I intend to include the end node in the count).

I have not been able to figure out e.g. how to use any LINQ extension methods to efficiently calculate this number, so I have implemented a counter like this (excluding all *null* and consistency checks):

```
var counter = 1;
var node = iStartNode;
while (!ReferenceEquals(node, iEndNode))
{
  node = node.Next;
  ++counter;
}
```

But there must be a more efficient solution, mustn't there? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a more efficient solution?

Comment: I maybe should have used the word _compact_ instead of _efficient_. From a performance point of view maybe the above solution is OK?

Comment: From a performance point of view, it's fine. See my answer for a more compact representation if you're happy to have a couple of extension methods which may be helpful elsewhere too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your solution to be the most efficient and also the most readable. Even if you can find an implementation in LINQ it will surely be tortuous.

By excluding `null` checks I presume you mean that the real code doesn't throw in the event of `node` running off the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. Actually, I have implemented my method so that it does throw when running off the end of the list, but in a controlled way. I verify that both the start and end nodes are contained in the same linked list, and that the start node appears before the end node. But that's maybe a different story...

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of which might be *slightly* cleaner - or at least, make general code working with linked list *nodes* slightly cleaner - would be to write two extension methods:

```
static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> AsEnumerable<T>
    (this LinkedListNode<T> node)
{
    // Can even call list.Head.AsEnumerable() when the list is empty!
    while (node != null)
    {
        yield return node;
        node = node.Next;
    }
}

static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> ReverseEnumerable<T>
    (this LinkedListNode<T> node)
{
    while (node != null)
    {
        yield return node;
        node = node.Previous;
    }
}
```

Then you could use LINQ:

```
var count = node.AsEnumerable().TakeWhile(x => x != endNode).Count();
```

That wouldn't include `endNode` itself, so you might want to increment it by 1. (It would be nice to have `TakeUntil` and `SkipUntil` methods which were like `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile`, but included the first predicate-non-matching node as the final one to take or skip.)

Note that this *wouldn't* go bang if it failed to find `endNode` - it would just give the count of the list from the start node onwards.

The nice thing about the extension methods is they basically let you operate on the list as a sequence from any point.

Comment: Thanks Jon for this interesting answer. I cannot see that you actually use the ReverseEnumerable method, have you included it only for completeness?
I definitely agree with your comment on TakeUntil/SkipUntil methods; I was initially searching for something similar in the framework, but since I couldn't find anything I reverted to the solution that I have outlined above.

Comment: @Anders: Absolutely. Given that you've *got* a doubly-linked list, I wouldn't put in the first extension method without the second :)

Comment: +1 for one of the least "tortuous" Linq queries that I have seen!   ;-)

Comment: @Anders: It's easy enough to write your own TakeUntil method if you want it of course :)

Comment: @Jon: We'll see; if my LinkedList needs expand I might just do that :-) Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @Anders: If it would be useful to you, I could always add it to MoreLINQ (http://morelinq.googlecode.com). I'd be happy to write that tonight if you like...

Comment: @Jon: If you do find the time and if you think it is of general interest, that would be most kind of you! And thanks for referring to the MoreLINQ project, I was not aware of it before.